# memory allocation in numpy.repeat

Tags: python, numpy, memory, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak in my script and I narrowed it down to `np.repeat`. In theory, if I have some `np.array` that has it's own pointer called `arr` and I make an `arr_repeated = arr.repeat(10, axis = 0)` and then do `del` on both of them, should the memory occupied by them get freed?

I'm checking with:

```
psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss
```

To be more specific, should `memory_before` and `memory_after` be different in the following code?

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,...], [...], [...]])
arr_repeated = arr.repeat(10, axis = 0)

memory_before = psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss 

del arr
del arr_repeated

memory_after = psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss
```

I have

> extra/python-numpy 1.13.1-2 [installed]

on my antergos/arch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you use `del` a variable doesn't mean the memory is freed immediately. It just deletes the name for the variable. Pythons reference counting mechanism and `gc` are responsible to free the memory.

So just to be on the safe side you need to use [`gc.collect`](https://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.collect) to force `gc` to clean up everything that may contain cyclic references, otherwise Python will clean these "whenever it wants" (probably only if memory is getting low or after a certain time).

For example [the documentation about `__del__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) contains this note:

> ### Note
>
> `del x` doesn’t directly call `x.__del__()` — the former decrements the reference count for `x` by one, and the latter is only called when `x`’s reference count reaches zero. Some common situations that may prevent the reference count of an object from going to zero include: circular references between objects (e.g., a doubly-linked list or a tree data structure with parent and child pointers); a reference to the object on the stack frame of a function that caught an exception (the traceback stored in `sys.exc_info()[2]` keeps the stack frame alive); or a reference to the object on the stack frame that raised an unhandled exception in interactive mode (the traceback stored in `sys.last_traceback` keeps the stack frame alive). The first situation can only be remedied by explicitly breaking the cycles; the second can be resolved by freeing the reference to the traceback object when it is no longer useful, and the third can be resolved by storing `None` in `sys.last_traceback`. Circular references which are garbage are detected and cleaned up when the cyclic garbage collector is enabled (it’s on by default). Refer to the documentation for the [gc](https://docs.python.org/library/gc.html) module for more information about this topic.

```
import numpy as np
import psutil
import os
import gc

arr = np.array([list(range(10000)), list(range(10000)), list(range(10000))])
arr_repeated = arr.repeat(10, axis = 0)

gc.collect()
memory_before = psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss

del arr
del arr_repeated

gc.collect()
memory_after = psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss
```

---

Note that `gc` also has a setting to detect leaks: `gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)` not sure how that works exactly but it could be worth a try instead of using `psutil`.

Comment: Yep, forgot about gc, I see now it works on a sample code. Doesn't work in my main script unfortunately but I guess there are some more links left somewhere

Comment: @gavlig It could still be a reference or memory leak, I was just saying that relying on `del` to clean the memory is a wrong assumption. If you really suspect a memory leak you should rather use some tool like valgrind or report it to the NumPy developers. :)

Comment: @gavlig Note that views keep the original array alive so if you have a 2x2 view of an 1000x1000 array and keep the view it will keep the 1000x1000 array alive! That's something that happened to me quite a few times. In those cases you can simply `copy` the view to remove the link to the original. But that's just guesswork without knowing your code - you may need to check this yourself.